# Добавление роли в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

После добавления кода, роль не появляется в списке выбора. Подскажите, что не так? Может что-то мешает созданию новой роли? Так как код идеальный).

```
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'mpg', 'mpg_activation' ) );

    function mpg_activation(){

    add_role('mpg_new',
          'New',
              array(
                  'read'          => true,
                  'edit_posts'    => true,
                  'delete_posts'  => true,
                  'publish_posts' => true
              )
      );
}
```

Функция прописана в плагине. Также уже прописаны определённые права для кастомного типа поста, которым будут управлять юзер с вышеуказанной ролью.

Инструкции читал:

- https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_role
- https://3.7designs.co/blog/2014/08/restricting-access-to-custom-post-types-using-roles-in-wordpress/
- https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-and-user-role/

Comment: У вас точно так класс называется - с маленькой буквы, просто 'mpg'? Почему не `array( $this, 'mpg_activation' )` ?

Comment: Для чего нужен $this при написании плагина? https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_role

Comment: я вижу, что вы совершенно не понимаете, что у вас написано в register_activation_hook. Вы разберитесь, зачем там array, тогда поймёте мой вопрос

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не верно использовал функцию активации плагина register_activation_hook. Правильно:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'mpg_activation' );

    function mpg_activation(){

    add_role('mpg_new',
          'New',
              array(
                  'read'          => true,
                  'edit_posts'    => true,
                  'delete_posts'  => true,
                  'publish_posts' => true
              )
      );
}
```

Comment: Хорошо, что разобрались. Приведите правильный вид хука активации, чтобы другие пользователи тоже смогли разобраться.